# Switch with 3 options in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

The default switch element only has two options on and off. I need one with 3 options, does anyone know where I can find a library for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Interface Builder you can change the number of segments to 3 and then double click on each segment to change the value.

If adding by code you can use the following:

```
UISegmentedControl *myControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 5, 125, 35)];
[myControl insertSegmentWithTitle: @"Easy" atIndex: 0 animated: NO ];
[myControl insertSegmentWithTitle: @"Hard" atIndex: 1 animated: NO ];
myControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
[myControl addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Comment: @Jim Note that this answer is the same as the earlier one that got all the votes: it's not a three-option switch, it's a UISegmentedControl.

Comment: Yes, but this one provides and explicit answer, so he doesn't have to follow the link provided by pratikshabhisikar and learn all about how UISegmentedControls work.

Comment: Sorry guys, its always better to study apple docs rather than just grab the answer that works. You would get the answer and get going but will not achieve anything more than that. I appreciate providing exact answer that users need, but from his question it seemed he didnt even know about segmented control, ideally we should allow him to learn what it is and best place is apple documentation.

Answer (score 10):

[UISegmentedControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html)?

Comment: The only other option after that is to make a custom three-stage switch.

Comment: +1 UISegmentedControl is the correct answer. A three-stage switch is most definitely not the appropriate control, completely violating the Human Interface Guidelines, to the point where it could result in app rejection.

Answer (score 2):

I would say `UISegmentedControl` as well, but if for some reason you must have that sliding action then a `UISlider` would work  - you can track the changes in code and "snap" to one of three settings as the user moves the control past a breakover point.  That would probably feel a lot like the three-way switch you are looking for while not being too weird.

Answer (score 0):

Their is no such library which has a switch with three options and if you want the switch with three options then in that case create a custom view for that by inheriting the UISwitch class.

Also if you find it hard to make the custom view then in that case you may use the segment control and implement it with three segments, here's a [tutorial](http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.com/2010/11/uisegmentedcontrol.html) on segment controls.